# Deleting PHAssetCollection (Swift)

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, phasset

I created an PHAssetCollection to house my photos for my app, and it works fine.  However, I am trying to have it so the user can delete the PHAssetCollection when they press a button.  How do I go about deleting the entire AssetCollection ("App Folder") that I created in the following code?

Code to create PHAssetCollection:

```
    let albumName = "App Folder" 

    //Check if the folder exists, if not, create it
    let fetchOptions = PHFetchOptions()
    fetchOptions.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", albumName)
    let collection:PHFetchResult = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithType(.Album, subtype: .Any, options: fetchOptions)

    if let first_Obj:AnyObject = collection.firstObject{
        //found the album
        self.albumFound = true
        self.assetCollection = first_Obj as! PHAssetCollection
    }else{
        //Album placeholder for the asset collection, used to reference collection in completion handler
        var albumPlaceholder:PHObjectPlaceholder!
        //create the folder
        NSLog("\nFolder \"%@\" does not exist\nCreating now...", albumName)
        PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({
            let request = PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.creationRequestForAssetCollectionWithTitle(albumName)
            albumPlaceholder = request.placeholderForCreatedAssetCollection
            },
            completionHandler: {(success:Bool, error:NSError!)in
                if(success){
                    println("Successfully created folder")
                    self.albumFound = true
                    if let collection = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollectionsWithLocalIdentifiers([albumPlaceholder.localIdentifier], options: nil){
                        self.assetCollection = collection.firstObject as! PHAssetCollection
                    }
                }else{
                    println("Error creating folder")
                    self.albumFound = false
                }
        })

    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    PHPhotoLibrary.sharedPhotoLibrary().performChanges({ () -> Void in

    PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.deleteAssetCollections([self.deleteTarget])

    }, completionHandler: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a class method in PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest called `deleteAssetCollections:` which does just that: requests that specific asset collections be deleted. Looking at the documentation it seems you can just call this with an array of PHAssetCollections like so:

```
PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.deleteAssetCollections(self.assetCollection)
```

Comment: This didnt work, but was close, it needed a completion handler...  I found the solution in my updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

just made it easy to use. hope it helps :
Here's function to delete custom album programmatically with error handeling

```
    func deleteAlbum(albumName: String){
        let options = PHFetchOptions()
        options.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "title = %@", albumName)
        let album = PHAssetCollection.fetchAssetCollections(with: .album, subtype: .any, options: options)


        // check if album is available
        if album.firstObject != nil {

            // request to delete album
        PHPhotoLibrary.shared().performChanges({
            PHAssetCollectionChangeRequest.deleteAssetCollections(album)
        }, completionHandler: { (success, error) in
            if success {
                print(" \(albumName) removed succesfully")
            } else if error != nil {
                print("request failed. please try again")
            }
        })
        }else{
            print("requested album \(albumName) not found in photos")
        }
    }
```

How to Use -

```
   deleteAlbum(albumName: "YourAlbumName")
```